# Excel VBA: Extract custom class from dictionary

Tags: class, vba, object, dictionary, casting

I am having a problem with VBA Excel 2010.  I've made a custom Class called 'Enclosure', created an instance of this and added it to a dictonary.
I **can** then loop through the keys to ensure it has been added.
I'm having trouble then extracting my enclosure class.  Here's my code for the extraction sub:

```
Sub AddEnclosureItem(sItemToAdd As String, ByRef rdEnclosures As Scripting.Dictionary, dDebug As Boolean)

Dim TempEnclosure As Enclosure ' hold enclosure we pull

TempEnclosure = rdEnclosures(1)

End Sub
```

When I try to compile I get the 'Object Variable or With block variable not set'

Any idea's on how to proceed?  I've read somewhere you can declare a dictionary stating the items are of a certain object but I can't get it to work in 2010.  That's all I can guess at. OR a way to cast the enclosure item as it comes out.

Comment: Try `Set TempEnclosure = rdEnclosures(1)`:-)

Comment: Hi Peter,
Yeah I figured this out and tried to answer but because I am new I have to wait for 7 hours more.  So a new question to you sir, Why do I need to Set?
I also had to set my accessors for a dictionary attribute within the class but forget why I did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign an object to a variable, you have to use the `Set` keyword.  The opposite of `Set` is `Let`, which is used to assign a value (not an object) to a variable.  The `Let` keyword is optional and almost nobody uses it anymore.

The reason there's a `Set` and `Let` is because most objects have a default property - meaning that if you reference an option without a property, it will return the value stored in the default property.  The `Value` property is a common default property.  This

```
x = Range("A1")
```

is the same as this

```
x = Range("A1").Value
```

is the same as this

```
Let x = Range("A1").Value
```

Any is acceptable (although I prefer the second one).  That's great if `x` is a Double or String, but if `x` is a Range object variable, you need use Set

```
Set x = Range("A1")
```

If you omit the `Set` keyword, VBA assumes you wanted `Let` and tries to assign the (default) `Value` property to `x`.  That gives the 'Object variable or with block not set' error because it's trying to assign a Double or String to a Range object variable.

Your custom class module probably doesn't have a default value, so none of this should matter.  But it does.  Even if there is no default value, you have to use Set to reference the object.

Comment: Thanks for this :)  In hind sight, the word 'set' makes it all make sense but then again it's only simple when you know it.  I have another issue related to this sitting at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141872/vba-dictionary-memory-problems-populate-dict-removeall-populate-issues

Be greatly appreciated if you could have a look.