# VBA: Dictionary Memory Problems? Populate dict, .removeall, populate issues

Tags: class, vba, object, excel, dictionary

So I'm using a bit of code here where I used one dictionary to populate two different dictionaries held as attributes within a custom class.  I do this for efficiency.

Note: I have a workaround solution of this issue by using a dictionary for each attribute I want to set but this is not overly efficient.

So roughly here's my code:

```
for iKey = 1 to class.maxnumber ' 8
    dTempDict.add iKey, cdbl(24)   ' enforce to 24 for calcs later
next iKey

Set class.dict1 = dTempDict ' commit to class.dict1

dTempDict.removeall 'wipe temp dictionary

for iKey = 1 to class.maxnumber ' 8
    dTempDict.add iKey, "word"   ' something other than 24 to test
next iKey

Set class.dict2 = dTempDict
```

So the above works fine. I tried then to loop through and print the keys of class.dict1 with no problem.  When I then tried to assign the values to a pre-declared dbl I got into trouble.  I then looped through each key like so in a different sub passing class byref:

```
dim dTempDict as scripting.dictionary
Set dTempDict = class.dict1 
for each iKey in dTempDict
 msgbox typename(dTempDict.Item(iKey))
next iKey
```

This brought back the result... "String"... confusing.  I then changed my valueholder to a string and it worked.  I have checked my accessors within the class and they don't loop back to the wrong dictionary attribute so it appears that, even though I assign them second and even do a .removeall, The values for my second dictionary get populated into the first.

Any ideas?

As said above, using a different temp dictionary for class.dict1 and class.dict2, they get assigned correct but this is still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this...

```
Set class.dict1 = dTempDict 
dTempDict.removeall 
'...
Set class.dict2 = dTempDict
```

... then both `dict1` and `dict2` point to the same Dictionary object (`dTempDict`).

Assigning one object variable to another doesn't create a copy of that object, but just results in an additional "pointer" to the same object.

You should create a new Dictionary rather than re-using the same one to assign to `dict2`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I don't like to have dictionaries in classes except to hold other classes.  I don't know your situation, so I can't comment on that.  But whatever '24' is, you might consider that it should be its own object and your class would contain another collection class.  Incidentally, I use collections rather than dictionaries for that purpose.  Then you access things like

```
clsDepartment.Employees.Count
```

instead of

```
clsDepartment.mydict(1)
```

Anyway, for what you have, you should populate the dictionary in the class rather than creating the temp dictionary.  If your class looks like this

```
Private mdcTwentyFour As Scripting.Dictionary
Private mdcNotTwentyFour As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Property Get TwentyFour() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set TwentyFour = mdcTwentyFour
End Property

Public Property Get NotTwentyFour() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set NotTwentyFour = mdcNotTwentyFour
End Property

Public Property Get MaxNumber() As Long
    MaxNumber = 8
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set mdcTwentyFour = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set mdcNotTwentyFour = New Scripting.Dictionary

End Sub
```

Then your sub might look like this

```
Sub FillClassDicts()

    Dim clsClass As CClass
    Dim i As Long

    Set clsClass = New CClass

    For i = 1 To clsClass.MaxNumber
        clsClass.TwentyFour.Add i, 24
        clsClass.NotTwentyFour.Add i, "word"
    Next i

    Debug.Print clsClass.TwentyFour.Count, clsClass.NotTwentyFour.Count
    Debug.Print TypeName(clsClass.TwentyFour(1)), TypeName(clsClass.NotTwentyFour(5))

End Sub
```